# How do you scaffold DbContext as a pre-build event

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.1, pre-build-event

I'm trying to set up our project to re-scaffold the DbContext and all the models before each build in order to catch any database changes within our API.  However when I set up the pre-build command and run/build the project, it just spawns a bunch of .NET Host tasks to take up the rest of my CPU and the build stalls forever. So then I have to open task manager and kill Visual Studio 2019.

I'm using VS 2019. This is a .Net Core 3 API with EF Core.
Here's an example of the command that I placed in the pre-build.  It runs fine in PMC.

`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --output-dir Models --force --context-dir Data --context APIContext`

How do I get this to work as a pre-build event?

Comment: That is not a good approach, why not include the database schema in source control instead?

Comment: @ErikEJ Why is it not a good approach. And what would including the schema in source control do for me?

Comment: That changes code-first into database-first, well, OK. My main objection would be that this adds a very expensive build step that's not necessary 99% of the times. Also, it's hard to do this in collaboration projects where everybody works in branches. Even if possible I'd never ever do it myself, but, admittedly, academically it's interesting.

Comment: You know that these commands internally run build, right? So apparently putting them into pre/post build events is not a good idea as it causes the equivalent of stack overflow.